# Reading .adf (TIN) map files using GDAL

Tags: gdal, tin, ascii

I have a set of maps in few formats :

- TIN

> ```
> ├── [4.0K]  info
> │   └── [2.6K]  arc.dir
> ├── [ 708]  log
> ├── [374K]  M-33-45-D-d-4.asc
> └── [4.0K]  m-33-45-d-d-4tin
>     ├── [  96]  tdenv.adf
>     ├── [1.1M]  tedg.adf
>     ├── [ 332]  thul.adf
>     ├── [8.2K]  tmsk.adf
>     ├── [ 116]  tmsx.adf
>     ├── [1.1M]  tnod.adf
>     ├── [751K]  tnxy.adf
>     └── [188K]  tnz.adf
> ```

- ASCII

> ```
> ├── [ 12K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_c.asc
> ├── [ 12K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_j.asc
> ├── [ 365]  M-33-45-D-d-4_k.asc
> ├── [1.6K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_o.asc
> ├── [518K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_p.asc
> ├── [114K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_pz.asc
> ├── [109K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_s.asc
> ├── [164K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_sz.asc
> └── [317K]  M-33-45-D-d-4_z.asc
> ```

- TTN

> ```
> └── [3.2M]  M-33-45-D-d-4.ttn
> ```

I would like to somehow interpret those maps (preferably TIN) for my visualization application but I am quite confused where to start.

I know about [GDAL library](http://www.gdal.org/index.html) but I am not able to use it on those files to convert them to anything else.

How can I read those .adf files?

Comment: For the first format 'TIN' that is an ArcInfo Workstation TIN format - do you have access to ArcGIS?

Comment: I don't have the access to ArcGIS but as I can see on the website they offer 30 day trial so it's ok. Why would you ask?

Comment: Well it is native to ArcGIS not much else will read that TIN format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at VTBuilder, found here:
http://vterrain.org/Doc/VTBuilder/overview.html
One of the supported formats is now ESRI ADF.

Comment: That's really good to know. I don't know many ways to read an Esri TIN (it's a proprietary format and not published); it is *very* old though, the structure dates back to ArcInfo coverages perahps Esri has published it at some stage. GDAL wouldn't be much good here either as TIN is neither raster nor vector. Does it rasterize the tin or display it as facets.

Answer (score 1):

It is an new feature in the future release QGIS 3.10. QGIS can now read ESRI TIN as this format is now supported by the [MDAL library](https://www.mdal.xyz/).

**Edit :** 
Finally, it seems it will available in the future release QGIS 3.12 (end of February 2020).